# copy constructor [array] C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I'm doing a puzzle game and I came to a problem. My Board will get scrambled later on in the program. I want to make a copy of it before it gets scrambled, to use it in the win-condition for my game. My Idea is to compare the copied board to the scrambled board every time the user moves a tile to see if they succeded (won) or not. But I'm a bit unsure how to do the copy constructor for the board. Here is what I have done(doesn't work as it's supposed to do).

`Board::Board(int userInput)
{
    this->gameSize = userInput;
    int zeroPos[2] = { 0, 0 };
    SetTileNumbers();
}

void Board::SetTileNumbers()
{
    const int sizeOfGame = gameSize;                        //Size given from user when the board was created.
    int tileNumber = 0;                                     //The value given to each Tile.Number.
    int row, column;

    boardOfTiles = new Tile* [sizeOfGame];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfGame; i++)
    {
        boardOfTiles[i] = new Tile [sizeOfGame];            //The doublepointer is given an additional dimension
    }

    for (row = 0; row < sizeOfGame; row++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < sizeOfGame; column++)
        {
            boardOfTiles[row][column].number = tileNumber;  //Loops that goes through the entirety to instantiate the board of tiles.
            tileNumber++;
        }
    }
}

void Board::SetTileNumbers(const Board& copy) 
{
    const int sizeOfGame = copy.gameSize;
    int row , column;
    boardOfTiles = new Tile*[sizeOfGame];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfGame; i++)
    {
        boardOfTiles[i] = new Tile[sizeOfGame]; 
    }

    for (row = 0; row < sizeOfGame; row++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < sizeOfGame; column++)
        {
            boardOfTiles[row][column].number = copy.boardOfTiles[row][column].number;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: In what way is it not working as expected?

Comment: What about using `std::array` and make your life easier?

Comment: What is your question? The code you posted isn't of a copy constructor.

Comment: if that's not copy constructor, what is? I thought that since I need a copy, i need to copy the first board and initialize it? Am I wrong?

Comment: Could I do a copy of Board::Board and then call SetTileNumbers() from the copy to make them the same?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this does not sound off-topic, but copy-constructor aside, I think you might have a different problem: the way you decide on a solution is very inefficient. You waste cpu time and you waste memory.

For every step to compare two NxN boards is about as ineffciciet as it gets. You can try a different approach: assign a number to each position on the board and you know that the solution is to have the numbers sorted in a particular order.

For a 3x3 board, 'THE' solution would look like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Furthermore, a 2d array is stored in memory as a continuous array, you you can treat the solution as an array:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Any other arrangement will not represent an solution.
Checking weather an array is sorted is a much easier problem to solve. Worst case scenario you are still looking at O(n^2) to check if the array is sorted but without the memory overhead. Plus I'm sure you can figure out a more efficient algorithm to check if the array is sorted.

I hope this helps...